# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

Guyz,am running into following error with the belwo code,where is ti going wrong?
any cleanup suggestions also accepted

```
    for line in file(timedir + "/change_authors.txt"):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file' referenced before assignment
```

Code below:

```
    import os,datetime
    import subprocess
    from subprocess import check_call,Popen, PIPE
    from shutil import copyfile,copy

def main ():
    #check_call("ssh -p 29418 review-droid.comp.com change query --commit-message status:open project:platform/vendor/qcom-proprietary/radio branch:master | grep -Po '(?<=(email|umber): )\S+' | xargs -n2")
    global timedir
    change=147441
    timedir=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
    #changeauthors = dict((int(x.split('/')[3]), x) for line in file(timedir + "/change_authors.txt"))
    for line in file(timedir + "/change_authors.txt"):
        changeauthors = dict(line.split()[0], line.split()[1]) 
    print changeauthors[change]
    try:
        os.makedirs(timedir)
    except OSError, e:
        if e.errno != 17:
            raise # This was not a "directory exist" error..
    with open(timedir + "/change_authors.txt", "wb") as file:
        check_call("ssh -p 29418 review-droid.comp.com "
            "change query --commit-message "
            "status:open project:platform/vendor/qcom-proprietary/radio branch:master |"
            "grep -Po '(?<=(email|umber): )\S+' |"
            "xargs -n2",
                shell=True,   # need shell due to the pipes
                stdout=file)  # redirect to a file

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `file()` to open a file on your filesystem: use `open` (at the line causing the error).

---

The documentation [recommends against it](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file):

> Constructor function for the file type, described further in section File Objects. The constructor’s arguments are the same as those of the open() built-in function described below.
>
> When opening a file, it’s preferable to use open() instead of invoking this constructor directly. file is more suited to type testing (for example, writing isinstance(f, file)).
>
> New in version 2.2.

Also, it's going away in Python 3.

Comment: thanks,is something wrong with line gerritauthors = dict(line.split()[0], line.split()[1]) ..basically am trying to split each line based on space and save the first string as index ,second string as element...

Comment: @user1927396 You could do `index, element = line.split(' ', 1)` to achieve this.

Comment: if I do that I keep getting TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 2 at line  changeauthors = dict(index,element)

Comment: @user1927396 If you want to add those to a dict, you should instantiate the dict first (`d = {}`) and then add the couple to the dict: `d[index] = element`.

Comment: This answer is true, but it's not actually the OP's problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is to do with functional scope. As your main function later defines its own file variable then the built-in file function is clobbered. As such when you initially try to call it it throws this error as it has reserved the local file variable for itself. If you were to take this code out of the main function or change the later reference to 'file' in your with open() statement it should work.

However I would do the following...

Instead of:

```
for line in file(timedir + "/change_authors.txt"):
```

You should use:

```
for line in open(timedir + "/change_authors.txt", 'r'):
```

The [open() function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) should be used to return a file object and is preferable to [file()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file).

Comment: its actually file,i dont know how was it working before,i have a script where for line in file() works